# JS file uploader with streaming, i.e. without loading the entire file into memory

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filereader

Something like the one described on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications), but without loading the file into memory, i.e. I'd like to be able to send the file in chunks using some streaming interface so that my client process is independent from the file size. The file is selected using an invisible `<input type=file>` element.

It's a real world problem: my users will be uploading multiple files at once, which may be big enough (and the client devices limited enough) to worry about memory consumption. At the same time, I'd like to provide a nice client-side uploader with progress indication.

The FileReader interface doesn't seem to be supporting streaming, unless I'm missing something of course.

The solution should work in the latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox, and if possible also in IE9 (although there is probably little hope). *Edit*: also no jQuery, just bare JavaScript.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am considering socket.io/WebSocket however the FileReader still may not stream.

Comment: Apparently you can stream it http://stackoverflow.com/a/25813769/2103767

Answer (score 0):

The only one that I know that has all those capabilities(Multiple file upload,  file contents stream uploads, Upload progress bar, etc), uses jQuery though, is called **jQuery File Upload Plugin**,  here go the url:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Yes, saw it already, need to look at the sources to understand how exactly they do streaming.

Comment: The link no longer works, please update it.