# filereader api on big files

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

My file reader api code has been working good so far until one day I got a 280MB txt file from one of my client. Page just crashes straight up in Chrome and in Firefox nothing happens.

```
// create new reader object 
var fileReader = new FileReader(); 

// read the file as text 
fileReader.readAsText( $files[i] );  
fileReader.onload = function(e) 
{   // read all the information about the file 
    // do sanity checks here etc... 
    $timeout( function() 
    {    
        // var fileContent = e.target.result;
        // get the first line 
        var firstLine = e.target.result.slice(0, e.target.result.indexOf("\n") ); }}
```

What I am trying to do above is that get the first line break so that I can get the column length of the file. Should I not read it as text ? How can I get the column length of the file without breaking the page on big files?

Comment: Example of how I managed to handle reading big files in browser line by line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377748/2358659

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your application is failing for big files because you're reading the full file into memory before processing it. This inefficiency can be solved by streaming the file (reading chunks of a small size), so you only need to hold a part of the file in memory.

A `File` objects is also an instance of a `Blob`, which offers the `.slice` method to create a smaller view of the file.

Here is an example that assumes that the input is ASCII (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mw99v8d4/).

```
function findColumnLength(file, callback) {
    // 1 KB at a time, because we expect that the column will probably small.
    var CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
    var offset = 0;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        var view = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
        for (var i = 0; i < view.length; ++i) {
            if (view[i] === 10 || view[i] === 13) {
                // \n = 10 and \r = 13
                // column length = offset + position of \r or \n
                callback(offset + i);
                return;
            }
        }
        // \r or \n not found, continue seeking.
        offset += CHUNK_SIZE;
        seek();
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
        // Cannot read file... Do something, e.g. assume column size = 0.
        callback(0);
    };
    seek();

    function seek() {
        if (offset >= file.size) {
            // No \r or \n found. The column size is equal to the full
            // file size
            callback(file.size);
            return;
        }
        var slice = file.slice(offset, offset + CHUNK_SIZE);
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
    }
}
```

The previous snippet counts the number of bytes before a line break. Counting the number of characters in a text consisting of multibyte characters is slightly more difficult, because you have to account for the possibility that the last byte in the chunk could be a part of a multibyte character.

Comment: You are officially my hero. At first, I had the same idea of reading it as a blob chunks instead of reading the whole thing but I did not know enough to make it work. You have no idea how much I appreciate this. Thank you!

Comment: What would you recommend if I need to determine the last chunk in the file? The system I'm working with has a different REST api for the last chunk which then commits the entire file. But I can't figure out how to determine that last piece. If you wouldn't mind looking at my question that would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312451/determining-the-last-file-chunk/39312577#39312577

Comment: I am wondering how I can use this to [read `n` lines from a big file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479090/read-n-lines-of-a-big-text-file)..... :/

Comment: As for the multibyte character dilemma, [TextDecoder#decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode) now/soon has a `stream` option flag for this very purpose.

Comment: @RobW how can we preview large image, chunk by chunk? if image size is >25mb each, total multiple image size is around 900mb to display? How can we set chunk by chunk view on img src?

Answer (score 5):

There is a awesome library called [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) that do that in a graceful way! It can really handle big files and also you can use web worker.

Just try out the demos that they provide: https://www.papaparse.com/demo

Comment: CSV parser? Is this helpful?

Comment: This is helpful whenever you want to deal with CSV files direct in the browser instead of send it to backend.

Comment: Just want to second what @EdySegura, PapaParse works amazingly well, and provides a much smoother user experience (as offline-first always is)