# Split a big file to be upload using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I have to split a big file into 2mb parts to be sended into a server but i could not find any way. on angular or javascript. Right now i am using angularFileUpload to get it and send it as a big file. if anyone have a clue please let me know

Comment: Stream the file and read it in chunks maybe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810051/filereader-api-on-big-files

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the HTML5 file API. More info about it you can find [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). I can't provide any code example, mainly because i don't know how your server looks. You have to give the user a transaction token, and he will have to send you the chunk number, chunk data and the token, so you'll be able to re-assemble it on the server.

Comment: i am reading FileApi i hope all of theses can soported by apiRest because on server side i have a c# app with controllers

Comment: Great! You can find an example of a server that accepts chunked uploads [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=460142&av=669590)

Comment: mmm i have ie6 + so blob can be used... do you any way?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you plan to target IE6+, you're kinda "doomed". IE6/7/8 doesn't offer an API to do this. You should consider using Adobe Flash, or, because you already know C#, Silverlight :(

Comment: uff our customers are now on IE9+ so i need to find an example of a server that accepts chunked uploads

Comment: That's great! See above, in my second comment. There's an example made by the guys at "the code project"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI). I believe it provides a shim for older browsers that do not support the HTML5 File API.

Here's an [**example**](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/44db8a87b168a0d113ddff8641cd46ba3cbcb3c5/demo/war/js/FileAPI.js) of it being used in the [angular-file-upload repo](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/44db8a87b168a0d113ddff8641cd46ba3cbcb3c5/demo/war/js/FileAPI.js).

Comment: i am reading FileApi i hope all of theses can soported by apiRest because on server side i have a c# app with controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code , This might help you to read file into chunks.
in HTML file . Here Filereader is reading as text, but we can choose other way like reading as buffer etc.

and in ts file

```
uploadDoc(event) {
    let lastChunksize = 0;
    var file = event.target.files[0];

    this.readFile(file, lastChunksize, this.myCallback.bind(this));

   }

   myCallback(file, lastChunksize, result) {
    lastChunksize = lastChunksize + 20000;
    if(result) {
      //Add you logic what do you want after reading the file
      this.readFile(file, lastChunksize, this.myCallback.bind(this));
    } else {
      ///end recursion
    }
   }

   readFile(file,lastChunksize: number, callback) {

    var fileBlob = file.slice(lastChunksize,lastChunksize+20000);
    if(fileBlob.size !=0) {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onloadend= (result)=>{
      return callback(file,lastChunksize,fileReader.result)
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(fileBlob);
    }else {
     return callback(file,lastChunksize,false);
    }
   }
```