# How to download 10GB file with Angularjs, Java, Tomcat,Spring and REST?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, tomcat

When I download small file , everything is OK , but I need some way to download large files . If file large, Blob didn't created , haven't enough memory. 
Download file without save on client , directly save to disk with many requests on the server or something like that.

My code on server is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oneFile/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getOneFile( @PathVariable("name") String name, HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) {
                ....
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
                response.flushBuffer();
```

On client and this is work for small size:

```
backupFileServer.downloadOneFileBrow(data)
                        .success(function(databack) {

                            var file = new Blob([ databack ], {
                                type : 'application/csv'
                            });
                            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.href = fileURL;
                            a.target = '_blank';
                            a.download = data;
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.click();
                        })
                        .error(function() {
                            alert($scope.DOWNLOAD_ERROR);
                        });
```

I tried something like this but didn't work :

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
                               a.href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(databack);
                               a.target = '_blank';
                               a.download = data;
                               document.body.appendChild(a);
                               a.click();
```

How someone idea how to do this or some example or code ....
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is just not the right solution for the problem. You should think in the direction of other ways, e.g. FTP, BitTorrent, ...

Comment: I would like if possible without FTP or BitTorrent or something like that ...  if possible ...  if not , I will must on that way .

Comment: You have a 10GB csv file?

Comment: It remains one of the ways, type is not problem.  If I download zip file of 500MB , everything works fine , but if I download zip file of 2GB or larger sizes I have problem from question .

Comment: my app is using spring boot service from where i am trying to send the 400 MB zip file to client.. but Save File box appears too late approx after 15 min .. not sure y .. my UI is Angular .. nto sure what wrong m doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split your file into multiple files and rebuild the file with your server.
Because it's bad practice to upload a big file without splitting it, the user can be disconnect at 99% of the upload and he need to upload the whole file again.

An example here : https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/

A good example here : http://ryansouthgate.com/2015/12/24/upload-amazon-s3-using-angularjs/ with Amazon S3 and their SDK.

Comment: This is going to be helpful, but if I understand this is to upload the file, I need something to download file ?

Comment: yes it's the same for download if you have a large file you need to split it into small chunks and the browser will recompile all the file at the end. Like https://mega.nz/  does I think. More informations here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27948228/861206