# Determining the last file chunk

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, filereader

I'm trying to setup a file upload through rest for large files. The function below is taking care of chunking but I need to be able to recognize the last chunk because my rest call changes to `/finishUpload()` in order to commit the save.

Right now I'm only able to figure out when the blob is empty but I can't figure out how to determine the last iteration before the blob is empty.

This is the script I'm using below to parse my files.

```
export default function parseFile(file, options) {
  var opts       = typeof options === 'undefined' ? {} : options;
  var fileSize   = file.size;
  var chunkSize  = typeof opts['chunk_size'] === 'undefined' ?  64 * 1024 : parseInt(opts['chunk_size']);
  var binary     = typeof opts['binary'] === 'undefined' ? false : opts['binary'] == true;
  var offset     = 0;
  var self       = this; // we need a reference to the current object
  var readBlock  = null;
  var chunkReadCallback = typeof opts['chunk_read_callback'] === 'function' ? opts['chunk_read_callback'] : function() {};
  var chunkErrorCallback = typeof opts['error_callback'] === 'function' ? opts['error_callback'] : function() {};
  var success = typeof opts['success'] === 'function' ? opts['success'] : function() {};

  var onLoadHandler = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.result == "") {
      console.log('Chunk empty, call finish');
      success(file);
      return;
    }

    if (evt.target.error == null) {
      chunkReadCallback(evt.target.result, offset).then(function() {
        offset += evt.target.result.length;
        readBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);
      });
    } else {
      chunkErrorCallback(evt.target.error);
      return;
    }
    if (offset >= fileSize) {
      success(file);
      return;
    }
  }

  readBlock = function(_offset, _chunkSize, _file) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    var blob = _file.slice(_offset, _chunkSize + _offset);
    console.log("blob size:", blob.size, "offset:", _offset, "C+S:",_chunkSize + _offset)
    r.onload = onLoadHandler;

    if (binary) {
      r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    } else {
      r.readAsText(blob);
    }
  }
  readBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/simkessy/pen/vXYbvW?editors=0011)

Comment: If you know the file size (you do, use `blob.size`) and the size of the last chunk, then you can first read the last chunk to get your desired data and then continue with what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not rely on the filesize, i.e. check the condition `_chunkSize + _offset >= fileSize`?

Comment: Not sure why but it's returning true all the time. http://codepen.io/simkessy/pen/vXYbvW?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

You can use `progress`, `loadend` events to process `File` object one byte at a time; define a variable where processing should be paused or stopped at nth byte, every nth byte, or any byte during processing of file.

```js
var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var type = "application/octet-stream";
var data = new Blob([], {
  type: type
});
var filename = "file.txt";
var reader = new FileReader();
var complete = false;
var beforeEnd = false;
var stopAt = str.length - 1;

function handleFile(e) {
  data = new File([data.slice()
                   , str.slice(data.size, data.size + 1)]
                   , filename, {
                       type: type,
                       lastModifiedDate: new Date()
          });
}

function handleRead(e) {
  if (data.size <= str.length && !complete) {
    if (data.size === stopAt && !beforeEnd) {
      beforeEnd = true;
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function() {            
        alert(`stopAt: ${stopAt}\n`
              +`data.size: ${data.size}\n`
              +`result at stopAt: ${r.result[stopAt -1]}`);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
      }
      r.readAsText(data);
    } else {
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data)
    }
  } else {
    console.log("complete")
  }
}

function handleProgress(e) {
  if (data.size <= str.length && !complete) {
    var read = new FileReader();
    read.onload = function() {
      if (!complete) {
        console.log(read.result);
        if (read.result.length === str.length) {
          complete = true;
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    }
    read.readAsText(data);
  }
}

reader.addEventListener("load", handleFile);

reader.addEventListener("loadend", handleRead);

reader.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
```