# SHA256 Hashing Large files in angular 6 using Filereader Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sha256, cryptojs

I have problem with SHA256 hashing. if the file size is more then 250 MB it is terminating browser and crashing. 
below is the hashing code please do help us.

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileToSend);

  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  const hash = CrypTo.SHA256(this.arrayBufferToWordArray(fileReader.result)).toString();
  this.hashCode=hash;
  this.fileHistory.MediaHash = hash;
  this.fileHistory.FileName = fileToSend.name;

  //Insert to file history
  this.fileHistoryService.postFiles(this.fileHistory).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.hashCode=data["MediaHash"];
      this.alertService.success('HASHFILE.FileUploadSuccessMessage', true);
      this.hideGenerateHashCodeButton = true;
    },
    error => {
       this.alertService.error('COMMONERRORMESSAGE.SomethingWentWrongErrorMessage');
  });

}

arrayBufferToWordArray(fileResult) {
    var i8a = new Uint8Array(fileResult);
    var byteArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
      byteArray.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
    }
    return CrypTo.lib.WordArray.create(byteArray, i8a.length);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below  code I tested for all the big files, which fixed my solution.

```
var hashdata = CrypTo.algo.SHA256.create();
      var file =**<FiletoHash>**;
          if(file){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var size = file.size;
            var chunk_size = Math.pow(2, 22);
            var chunks = [];

            var offset = 0;
            var bytes = 0;
        reader.onloadend = (e) =>{
              if (reader.readyState == FileReader.DONE){

               //every chunk read updating hash
                hashdata.update(this.arrayBufferToWordArray(reader.result));

                let chunk:any = reader.result;
                bytes += chunk.length;
                chunks.push(chunk);
                if((offset < size)){
                  offset += chunk_size;
                  var blob = file.slice(offset, offset + chunk_size);
                  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
                } else {
                  //use below hash for result
                  //finaly generating hash
                  var hash = hashdata.finalize().toString();

                 //debugger;
                };
              }
            };
            var blob = file.slice(offset, offset + chunk_size);
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
          }

    }
  }

  arrayBufferToWordArray(fileResult) {
    var i8a = new Uint8Array(fileResult);
    return CrypTo.lib.WordArray.create(i8a, i8a.length);
  }
```

Comment: I got the general idea of your algorithm. `bytes` and `chunks` are not used, tho, which is weird. Also, if you store each result in a chunk, aren't you loading the whole file in memory? Why are you binding `onloadend` instead of `onload`? The later removes the need for your first `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use streams or something like it to avoid loading all the file into your memory.

Specifically using [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/), I have seen that it's possible to perform progressive Hashing.

```
var sha256 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
sha256.update("Message Part 1");
sha256.update("Message Part 2");
sha256.update("Message Part 3");
​
var hash = sha256.finalize();
```

So, use `FileReader` to read parts of the file, then every time you read a part, you update the sha256 until there is nothing more to read.

---

See :

[filereader api on big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810051/filereader-api-on-big-files)

Comment: Link you gave I tried, but it is not working in typescript. Can you have any solution for typescript?

Comment: I've found theses article, does it help ? : https://gist.github.com/ahoward/4394394 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810051/filereader-api-on-big-files

Comment: I tried with the above solution to generate sha256 hash. but it is giving different hash. can any one give me the full solution

Comment: Whatever approach NEUT explained is correct, but in typescript i am not able to solve the problem, please do help me for this.