# Angular 8 - Split file into smaller chunks

Tags: angular, file

Is there any angular library that can split file into smaller chunks and send it to a backend.

For example:
Split 100 MB file into chunks of size 5 MB and send it to an API.

Comment: Did you use anything or you are looking for suggestions only?

Comment: I've saw Plupload JS supports the functionality, but there is no angular wrapper for that library. Possibly looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, I can suggest you possibly two libs:

1. [ng7-large-files-upload-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng7-large-files-upload-lib)
2. [angular-material-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload)

If they don't work as expected you should refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810051/filereader-api-on-big-files) link. The answer here has JS code that can help you manually divide the big file and send it to the backend.